# How to concatenate multiple String elements using one simple statement

Tags: javascript

I'm concatenating strings like this:

```
function concate() {
var e = "test1, test2, test3";
  let defaultTokenList= ["abc", "cvcb"];
    let list = e.split(",");
    list.push(...defaultTokenList);
    list.join(",");
}
```

This gives me these results:

```
"test1, test2, test3, abc, cvcb"
```

Perfect.
Now is there a way to get the stuff written in the above function in one line? I feel like I'm using too many of lines of code just for concatenation?
Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you wish to sacrifice already clean and readable code in favor of a one-liner?

Comment: The provided example code will not return the result of `"test1, test2, test3, abc, cvcb"` due to the not correctly invoked `split` method. If one gives up on `push` and spread syntax in favor of `concat` one already gets a full chain ... see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this?

```
 var e = 'test1, test2, test3' + ', ' + ['abc', 'cd'].join(', ');
```

Sample code

```js
console.log('test1, test2, test3' + ', ' + ['abc', 'cd'].join(', '));
```

However, if I were you, I wouldn't bother too much with how many lines my code has, instead, I would focus on making it readable.

Comment: `"test1, test2, test3" + ", " + ['abc', 'cd'].join(', ');`

Comment: Missing a comma
```"test1, test2, test3" +","+  ["abc", "cvcb"].join(",");```

Comment: PO question is `test1, test2, test3` **and not** `test1, test2, test3, `

Comment: thumbs_up — OP asks for line but (hey user1234) there should _really_ be a separate line outside of this for `const defaultTokenList= ["abc", "cvcb"];`

Answer (score 1):

The OP's provided example code has to be refactored anyhow in order to return the pretended result of `"test1, test2, test3, abc, cvcb"` (which it does not yet). Thus, while fixing the `split` invocation and especially with replacing the original *push and spread-syntax* ... `.push(...defaultTokenList)` ... by `.concat(defaultTokenList)` one already comes pretty close to what can be later turned most easily into a one liner, if needed ...

```js
function concat(tokenString) {

  const defaultTokenList= ['abc', 'cvcb'];

  return String(tokenString)
    // the split-regX sanitizes any kind of comma/whitespace separation.
    .split(/\s*,\s*/)
    .concat(defaultTokenList)
    .join(', ');
}

function oneLineConcat(tokenString) {
  return String(tokenString).split(/\s*,\s*/).concat(['abc', 'cvcb']).join(', ');
}

console.log(
  "(concat('test1 ,  test2 ,  test3') === 'test1, test2, test3, abc, cvcb') ?",
  (concat('test1 ,  test2 ,  test3') === 'test1, test2, test3, abc, cvcb')
);
console.log(
  "(oneLineConcat('test1,test2,test3') === 'test1, test2, test3, abc, cvcb') ?",
  (oneLineConcat('test1,test2,test3') === 'test1, test2, test3, abc, cvcb')
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

var e = `test1,test2,test3,${['abc','cd'].toString()}`;
// "test1,test2,test3,abc,cd"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDa65.png)

Comment: The `toString` of `['abc','cd'].toString()` is not even necessary. The variable interpolation of the template string already does it ... `\`test1,test2,test3,${['abc','cd']}\`` or even `'test1,test2,test3' + ['abc','cd']` already does the trick.